# javascript overlay on a custom html element

Tags: javascript, css, position, overlay

I am trying to make a simple Overlay module that would enable me to put overlay on a custom DOM element. The problem is that css for the overlay div specifies position:absolute. But element on which the overlay should be applied can have position:static in which case the overlay is applied incorrectly. How to overcome this issue? I have come up with this but I am not sure if it is good.

```
//js
if ($(elem).css('position') == 'static') {
   $(elem).css('position', 'relative');
}
$('<div></div>').prependTo(elem).addClass('overlay').css('z-index', 100);

// css
div.overlay {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: #000;
    opacity: 0.75;
    filter: alpha(opacity=75);
}
```

Comment: Is it necessary to prepend the element to the target?
You could detach the overlay and append it to the body and use width, height, offset of the target element to position the overlay

Comment: @ThomasAndersen: that is a good idea. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The suggestion of Thomas Andersen works. A slight disadvantage is a bit higher complexity and that position of the overlay is not pinned to the position of the element. Another approach could be to do it like this:

```
div.overlay {
    position: absolute;
    background: #000;
    opacity: 0.75;
    filter: alpha(opacity=75);
}

var width = $(elem).width();
var height = $(elem).height();
$('<div></div>')
    .width(width)
    .height(height)
    .prependTo(elem)
    .addClass('overlay')
    .css('z-index', 100)
```

Here I am setting position:absolute without specifying top/left which should cause the overlay to be taken out of the flow while keeping its offset. Uncommon usage, I guess, but I believe I can rely on this.

The original solution I have proposed is a real hack and caused me some problems already.